# Error when attempting to predict with estimator (matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, train-test-split

I have a dataset with 329 features because of one hot encoding and I am trying to fit and predict them with a linear regression after splitting them up into training and test set.

When I try to predict with my y_test I get this error

```
lr.predict(y_test)
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 675.   1348.48 2099.   1899.    459.   1398.99 1799.   1499.   1629. .....]
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

So I reshaped the y_test and then I got this

```
lr.predict(np.array(y_test).reshape(-1,1))
matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 329 is different from 1)
```

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks

Comment: reshape(1,-1) ?

Comment: I actually realised just now that I should have used X_test.. my bad

Comment: You can delete your question in that case :)